# elegant atomic distributed locking from bash/python?

Tags: bash, ssh, python3, lock

In order to ensure non-concurrent execution of some code by multiple processes on a single node, I can implement advisory locking based on some atomic command (e.g. `ln` or `mkdir`) or I can use `flock`.

How can I ensure non-concurrent execution of some code by multiple processes on *multiple* nodes (i.e. allow only one running instance on the network)? I want to do this from a bash or python script on Linux.

I know I can use NFS locking or Redis but I don't want this complexity overhead. Pubkey-based ssh is available. I don't want the overhead of an extra machine to act as lock manager. Ideally, the admin should not need to nominate one of the nodes as lock manager. I don't need to be concerned about quorum: there is no need to continue execution if any node becomes unreachable.

Ideally, there would be a command I could invoke on all nodes like:

```
distlock --lock --nodes=nodeA,nodeB,nodeC --resource=resourceX || error "can't lock"
...
distlock --unlock --nodes=nodeA,nodeB,nodeC --resource=resourceX
```

The best I've come up so far (from thinking and from googling), is that each node follows this procedure:

1. read node list from config file (this file is to be created manually and copied to all nodes)
2. determine the lock manager node to be the alphabetically first node in the node list
3. if the currently running instance of the script *is* on the determined lock manager node then create a local lockfile in the usual manner (with the pid in the lockfile)
4. if the currently running instance of the script is *not* on the determined lock manager node then:

   1. fork an `ssh` to the determined lock manager node (e.g. using `coproc` from bash)
   2. get it to create the lockfile and ...
   3. get it to read from its stdin (which will be plumbed from the main script) a line of text (which it will not receive yet as the main script hasn't sent it, thereby keeping the pid file non-stale from the determined lock manager node's point of view)
5. execute the code I want to protect
6. release the lock (either by removing the lockfile if the locking is local, or sending the aforementioned line of text to the forked ssh and awaiting its exit if the locking is remote).

This fulfils my requirements: if multiple nodes execute the above code in parallel then precisely one will succeed in locking and the others will fail; if network connections fail then one node (the self-determined lock manager) can continue to work but others cannot (i.e. the cluster becomes half-brained, but not split-brained).

However, I'd like to canvas other people for ideas for alternative, more elegant solutions using simple easily-scriptable tools.

Comment: It's not really a python3 problem or even a Unix/Linux problem but the proper use of an algorithm typically used in clusters, involving quorum, adding nodes in the cluster etc. (for NFS it's simpler because the NFS server is a single point of failure). I don't think UL SE is a good fit for your question, but I wouldn't know if SO is either (it usually requires you to show actual code).

Comment: Algorithms exist but I'm aware of no command line tools. Logically, without a single node to orchestrate (eg NFS or Redis) every node must agree to lock acquisition. This would require every node to run some kind of daemon to support locking. So your hypothetical "dostlock" would also require a hypothetical "dostlockd" daemon.

Comment: Why use file lock? How about just opening a listener on a specific port? If nothing is listening, assume that host does not run distlock right now and ignore it for now. Else ask the age. The oldest distlock is the manager. Ask the manager for the lock on the resource. The manager will keep locks in ram. Optionally: the manager will replicate the locks to its peers, so if the server dies, the locks are not lost. Optionally: When a distlock using process is active on this server, remote distlocks can ask if that process is still running, so a lock can be released if a remote server dies.

Comment: What about a token ring type of solution, or "passing the conch". There is only one conch, and whoever has it can do the action. When done it passes the conch on to the next node. If that node has no action to do it passes it on to the next, etc.